# How to reference one object on click instead of all with same name

Tags: jquery

I have this structure multiple times in my website, two buttons called leftArrow and rightArrow (same name)

```
<div class="row">
  <ul>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="col-12 text-right">
    <button name="leftArrow" class="btn btn-primary" type="button"><</button>
    <button name="rightArrow" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

When clicked it scrolls the parent ul, this is my code:

```
$('button[name="leftArrow"]').click(function () {
    var mainSlider = $('button[name="leftArrow"]').parent().prev();
    var leftPos = mainSlider.scrollLeft();
    mainSlider.animate({
        scrollLeft: leftPos - 600
    }, 300);
});

$('button[name="rightArrow"]').click(function () {
    var mainSlider = $('button[name="rightArrow"]').parent().prev();
    var leftPos = mainSlider.scrollLeft();
    mainSlider.animate({
        scrollLeft: leftPos + 600
    }, 300);
});
```

this works fine, my problem is all uls get scrolled instead of only the only one who got clicked.

Any solution to referenciate only the ul that contain the button that is being clicked and not all uls?

Comment: Use `var mainSlider = $(this).parent().prev()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
var mainSlider = $('button[name="rightArrow"]').parent().prev();
```

to

```
var mainSlider = $(this).parent().prev();
```

You have already referenced the appropriate arrow on the click event. What you are doing is selecting all right arrows currently